# FSM export using Yosys

Tags: verilog, fsm, yosys

I am using [Yosys](http://www.clifford.at/yosys/files/yosys_manual.pdf) to synthesize my Verilog designs. I want to export the FSM in my Verilog design using the Yosys command `fsm_export`, but it does not generate anything. I wonder how is this command supposed to be called.

The series of commands I called were:

`read_verilog qwerty.v ; fsm_export`

If the generation is successful, and I have the FSM in KISS2 format, does anyone know what open source tools will allow me to visualize the FSM?

Comment: If you just want to see your FSM as a diagram, I know that Altera QuartusII (FPGA synthesis tool) is able to generate STD for FSMs. The Webpack is free and does this, though it doesnt work on more complex FSMs and Im not sure what exactly you need. As for Yosys and KISS2, Im not sure what youll be able to find as they dont seem that popular in the already limited space of RTL/FSM level design :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `fsm_export` command operates on extracted FSMs (i.e. `$fsm` cells). In order to create a state where the design contains such FSM cells, you first need to detect FSMs (`fsm_dectect`) and then extract them (`fsm_extract`). See `help fsm` for more information on the FSM flow.

The easiest way to get to such a state is to simply run `fsm -nomap`. Example script:

```
read_verilog test.v
proc; opt; fsm -nomap
fsm_export -o test.kiss2
```

For example consider for the following `test.v` file.

```
module test(input clk, rst, ctrl, output [3:0] O);
    reg [1:0] state;
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        O <= 0;
        if (rst) begin
            state <= 0;
        end else case (state)
            0: begin
                state <= ctrl ? 1 : 2;
                O <= 1;
            end
            1: begin
                O <= 2;
                if (ctrl) begin
                    state <= 2;
                    O <= 3;
                end
            end
            2: begin
                O <= 4;
                if (ctrl) begin
                    state <= 3;
                    O <= 5;
                end
            end
            3: begin
                if (!ctrl)
                    state <= 2'b00;
            end
        endcase
    end
endmodule
```

The script above will produce the following `test.kiss2` file. (I have [just fixed a bug in fsm_detect](https://github.com/cliffordwolf/yosys/commit/b7535a6c750108697161a72b5f2fe0001d0dd375), so use current git head.)

```
.i 2
.o 3
.p 12
.s 4
.r s0
-1 s0 s0 100
00 s0 s1 100
10 s0 s2 100
-1 s1 s0 001
00 s1 s1 001
10 s1 s3 001
-1 s2 s0 010
10 s2 s1 010
00 s2 s2 010
00 s3 s0 000
-1 s3 s0 000
10 s3 s3 000
```

Note: The FSM outputs in this case are not directly the four `O` signal bits. Instead Yosys created an FSM with a three bit output and an encoder outside of the FSM for creating the four `O` signal bits.

Regarding visualization: Unfortunately I don't know of any GUI tool to display KISS2 files (which does not mean that no such tool exists). But it is quite easy to create a GraphViz `.dot` file from a KISS2 file, for example using the following python script (`kiss2dot.py`).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import fileinput

print("digraph fsm {")

for line in fileinput.input():
    if not line.startswith("."):
        in_bits, from_state, to_state, out_bits = line.split()
        print("%s -> %s [label=\"IN=%s,\\nOUT=%s\"];" % (from_state, to_state,
                in_bits.replace("-", "?"), out_bits.replace("-", "?")))

print("}")
```

Example usage:

```
python3 kiss2dot.py test.kiss2 > test.dot
xdot test.dot
```

This will display the following graph:

[image: xdot output]

Answer (score 0):

Updated script for 2023 (https://github.com/YosysHQ/yosys/issues/3831):

```
read_verilog test.v
proc
opt -nodffe -nosdff
fsm -nomap
fsm_export -o test.kiss2
```

As single command:

`yosys -p 'read_verilog test.v; proc; opt -nodffe -nosdff; fsm -nomap; fsm_export -o test.kiss2'`